# find min values by each element index in a list of objects

Tags: python

I have this object instances below which has pid and pos list which the elements can range from 3-10, I will use three elements for now.

```
lst = []

class Ppl:
    def __init__(self, pid):
        # local variables
        self.pid = pid
        self.pos = [3*pid+6, 1, 10+pid-4*pid] 

for index in range(3):        
    lst.append(Ppl(index))

for index in range(len(lst)):
    print(lst[index].pos)
```

which results:

```
[6, 1, 10]
[9, 1, 7]
[12, 1, 4]
```

I need a way to get min values of those three by each index and make list comprehension such that the **expected output** should be:

```
[6, 1, 4]
```

What I have tried out so far:

I have tried this way which is actually not good approach, because it will work only if the list objects and the 'pos' list elements are three only.

```
lst2 = []
for index in range(len(lst)):   
    rst = min(lst[0].pos[index],lst[1].pos[index],lst[2].pos[index])
    lst2.append(rst)
print(lst2) 
>> [6, 1, 4]
```

Another approach which only works if the list is not object instances... but it isn't the way I want.

```
lst3 = [[6, 1, 10], [9, 1, 7], [12, 1, 4]]  

lst3 = list(map(min, *lst3))
print(lst3)
>> [6, 1, 4]
```

So how to do it?

Comment: You need to combine your first piece of code which produces some lists with your last which takes some lists and gives you what you want. -- And, yes, I've deliberately missed out a key term that you need to know about to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do that:

```
lst[]
n = 5
for index in range(n):        
    lst.append(Ppl(index))

result = list(map(min, *[x.pos for x in lst]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to process an existing list of lists like you show, where the each list can be of any length, as long as all of the inner lists are of the same length:

```
from functools import reduce

data =  [[6, 1, 10],
        [9, 1, 7],
        [12, 1, 4]]

mins = []

len = len(data[0])
for i in range(len):
    mins.append(reduce((lambda x, y: [min(x[i], y[i])] * len), data)[0])

print mins
```

Result:

```
[6, 1, 4]
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if the OP wanted to work on his Ppl objects or on the raw data.  It seems he added another piece of code showing what he'd tried that was a) better than mine (`lst3 = list(map(min, *lst3))`) and said that this isn't what he wants.  So I don't see my answer being very valuable here.  But it DID get an upvote.  I'm not worried about the points.  Maybe I should delete it?  - his answer taught me something too.  I'm new to functional programming.

Answer (score 2):

You could just find the number of elements in the array of just the first instance of the class (every instance must have the same number of elements in their positions array)

```
lst2 = []

numOfObjects = len(lst) #number of instances of the class 'Ppl'

numElements = len(lst[0].pos) #number of elements in array of EACH class instance

for index in range(numElements):

    rst = min([lst[i].pos[index] for i in range(numOfObjects)])
    lst2.append(rst)

print (lst2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code

```
import  numpy as np

lst = []

class Ppl:
    def __init__(self, pid):
        # local variables
        self.pid = pid
        self.pos = [3*pid+6, 1, 10+pid-4*pid]

for index in range(3):
    lst.append(Ppl(index))
a=[]
for index in range(len(lst)):
    # print(lst[index].pos)
    a.append(lst[index].pos)

print(np.min(a,axis=0))
```